# How to erase an object saved with NSUserDefaults from disk

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

Let's say I saved data to disk like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:theArray] forKey:@"savedArray"];
```

How can I erase that from disk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"savedArray"];
```